# chart.js - Add corporate design to chart

Tags: chart.js

I have to add a corporate design to my charts. My coworker told me that chartjs has a function to add a logo, but I can't find such function or property.

How exactly does it work?

Answer (score 0):

There's an option to customize your tooltip.

See here for more information: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#external-custom-tooltips

Comment: Add the actual code in the answer. Links can be broken and outdated.

Comment: An example would be great.